# !!! 5 という表記はなにを表していますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, haml

`app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`

の1行目で

`!!! 5`

という表記がありましたが、これは何を意味しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

それは`<!DOCTYPE html>`を表しています。

`.haml`という拡張子が示すとおり、それはHamlというテンプレート言語で書かれたものであり、HTMLに変換されます。`<!DOCTYPE html>`はHTML5のDOCTYPE宣言であり、それに対応するHamlの記法が`!!! 5`です。

[Hamlのドキュメントの!!!の節](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#doctype-)に説明があります。